# How to read file from Google Drive after it was updated?

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I need to place .csv file somewhere and then update it on daily basis for code to read it. The situation is the person who will be updating file will not be using coding, and it should be as easy as to upload from web for him. I read tens of question here about how to read or download file from Google Drive, Google storage but all of them suppose updating with code or downloading using API. I want little bit simpler solution. For example,
I'm using the code below to read the .csv file from google drive (this file is, for example, actual will be different).

This is the file which will be updated each day, however each time I update file (remove and upload new one into google drive) the link changes.

Is there a way to update file every time but not making change to code?

For example to make code to get file from the particular folder on Google Drive?

The main thing is that I need to do it without using API and Google Oauth.

If it's not possible where could the file be uploaded for this purpose? I need to be able to upload file every day without any code so code will read update data. Is there storage like this?

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from io import StringIO

url='https://drive.google.com/file/d/1976F_8WzIxj9wJXjNyN_uD8Lrl_XtpIf/view?usp=sharing'

file_id = url.split('/')[-2]
dwn_url='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=' + file_id
url2 = requests.get(dwn_url).text
csv_raw = StringIO(url2)
df = pd.read_csv(csv_raw)
print(df.head())
```

Answer (score 1):

## create vs update

The first thing you need to be sure is that the first time you run your code you use the [file.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create) method.

However when you updated the file you should be using [file.update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update) this should not be creating a new file each time.  There by your id will remain the same.

## google api python client

IMO you should consider using the python client library this will make things a little easer for you

```
updated_file = service.files().update(
    fileId=file_id,
    body=file,
    newRevision=new_revision,
    media_body=media_body).execute()
```

## Google sheets api

You are editing a csv file. By using the google drive api you are downloading the file and uploading it over and over.

Have you consider converting it to a google sheet and using the google sheet api to edit the file programmatically.  May save you some processing.

Comment: I agree with @DaImTo answer. You can see this video in Google Documentation about the revision of files if you want to keep working with using CSV files. Here is the [link](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/change-overview)

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer! The issue is, the person who need to update file doesn't know coding and so on. There would be code and separate person responsible to update file on daily basis. That's why I'm looking the way someone could update this file not dealing with code

Comment: Well then you are in the wrong place.  Stack overflow is a coding site any solution you get from here is going to be a coding solution..